# Obtaining the name of a data frame as a string in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a function that takes a data frame as an argument. In that function I need to use `if/else` construct to do some actions based on the data frame used as argument. for example, I need to be able to say

`if (name of data frame=="Anthro_Data") {do this}
 else if (the name of data frame=="Sports") {do that}`.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to get the name of the data frame (as a string) in order to use it. Any suggestions!

Comment: This seems like a very odd way to define a function. Since who is calling the function knows where the data.frame came from (in theory) shouldn't you just call different functions depending on the contents of the data.frame rather than hard coding a particular variable name in a function?

Comment: @ MrFlick, Thanks for the comment. The task for my function is to do some aggregation and return an aggregated data frame. my data frames have different dimensions/column names so I either use your approach or my approach. I am not an experienced programmer and don't know the best practice but this seemed like a solution to me. I thought it would be just less confusing to call one function on my five data frames rather than sourcing and calling 5 functions with different names that will eventually do the same task.

Comment: If you want to do different things based on what's passed in, I would suggest doing things like looking at the column names (if that's what's important to you). That's more flexible than requiring a particular variable name to be passed in.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you so much for commenting on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `deparse` and `substitute` to get the name of the argument passed to your function:

```
a <- 1
f <- function(arg) deparse(substitute(arg))
f(a)
# [1] "a"
```

Comment: ...I was only going to add as an aside that I would probably prefer to do this using an attribute on the data frame, rather than deparsing the name.

Comment: thanks @joran for the other suggestion